# Getting the file name of latest unpacked file using shutil.unpack_archive

Tags: python, python-3.x, archive, shutil

I am using `shututil` to unpack my archive like this:

```
shutil.unpack_archive(file_path, extract_dir=extract_path)
```

Unpacking works fine, but I want to be able to store the latest unpacked file name into a variable somehow and then use it later. In the documentation ([shutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html)), I don't see how I can access the filename inside the archive. (note that the unpacked filename might differ from the unpacked archive)

Any ideas on how I can achieve this or even print the status of the extraction?

Answer (score 0):

You can use os.listdir(..) before and after extraction.